# jQuery: Событие при наведении на ссылку (появление div)

Tags: jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно реализовать следующее:

Есть список ссылок на новости. Рядом с каждой ссылкой есть `div` с `visible:none`. `Div` - панель действия с новостью (редактирование, блокирование, удаление). Как реализовать чтобы при наведении на ссылку с новостью (н-р, id=3) появлялся соответствующий `div`.

Может быть, использовать такую конструкцию

```
$('#link-news').hover(function(){
    $('#div-panel').show();
}
```

Но как здесь использовать шаблоны:

```
$('#link-news1').hover(function(){
    $('#div-panel1').show();
}
$('#link-news2').hover(function(){
    $('#div-pane2').show();
}
```

и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут на самом деле есть несколько путей решения задачи.

Один из них - это каждому диву проставить идентификатор, а каждой панели прописать один класс, примерно вот так:

```
<ul>
    <li data-id="block1">...</li>
    <li data-id="block2">...</li>
</ul>

<div id="block1"></div>
<div id="block2"></div>
```

Как бы способ универсальный, но попахивает костыльностью

```
$('ul > li').hover(function() {
    $($(this).data('id')).show();
});
```

---

Следующий способ более правильный, с точки зрения вопроса. Т.е. у вас выходит как-то так:

```
<div>
    <a href='#' class='link'>...</a>
    <span>tools</span>
</div>
```

Как видим, используется один класс для ссылок, соответственно на js код такой:

```
$('.link').hover(function() {
    $(this).next().show(); // получаем следующий за данным .link элемент (т.е. span)
}, 
function() {
    $(this).next().hide();
});
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Ваши советы очень помогли!

Answer (score 1):

Все замечательно, если бы не одно НО. При таком решении при наведении на ссылку блок показывается, а при покидании курсором мышки - блок прячется.

Есть более правильное решение:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
<div class="linc2">Div</div>
```

CSS:

```
.linc2{
display:none;
width:100px;
height:100px;
background-color:red;
}
```

JS:

```
var linc2 = $('.linc2'),
    timeoutId;
$('.link').hover(function(){
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    linc2.show();
}, function(){
    timeoutId = setTimeout($.proxy(linc2,'hide'), 1000)
});
linc2.mouseenter(function(){
    clearTimeout(timeoutId); 
}).mouseleave(function(){
    linc2.hide();
});
```

[Демо](http://jsfiddle.net/V6VWC/4/)